# batch processing and merging in r

Tags: r, batch-processing

I have a list of .csv files and I need to delete the first three rows in all of them. Is there a way to do them all at once?

The code to do individually for a file named 'test' is:
    test<-test[-c(1:3),]

I want to run the above line for the list of files I've imported using:
    filenames <- list.files(path = getwd())

After processing the above files, I want to make a single file by using cbind. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can try following and see if it works.

```
result <- do.call(cbind, lapply( list.files(path = getwd()), function(n) read.csv(file=n , skip = 3) ))
```

Comment: Nope. I get the same error message. I forgot to mention, I had to add header=FALSE in read.csv because the first 3 lines are sentences and fourth line is the header. That's why I needed to delete the first 3 lines.

Answer (score 1):

```
csvlist <- lapply(csvnames, function(nam) read.csv( file=nam) )
do.call( cbind, lapply(csvlist, "[", -c(1:3)) )
```

Your question implied you had a successful input strategy but you now reporting errors, so you should give a better description of your files. It *might* work better to exclude the first three rows:

```
csvlist <- lapply(csvnames, function(nam) read.csv( file=nam, header=FALSE, skip=3) )
do.call( cbind, csvlist )  # no longer need to remove since skip=3 did that.
```

Are you sure you don't want to `rbind` instead of `cbind`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response @Dwin. It gives error message for the second statement:
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :  arguments imply differing number of rows:

Comment: @Bhante I think error says than your files have different number of rows. hence error while doing cbind

Comment: You're right. Can it cbind for different number of rows? I tried for another data with different number of rows; it works without giving errors; data is replicated in the column with smaller number of rows. But it's not working in this one.